# Why am I not using the version of java that I choose, and what to do?

Tags: 16.04, java

**[10/11/19 update with multiple lines]**
Thanks. When I echo $PATH and clean it up, I get the following:

[image]

The last entry is where I extracted both JRE and JDK tarballs. It's added by /etc/profile.

I don't know where the duplicate /home/lew/bin or the extraneous references to java 12 still come from (earlier failed attempt to use v12). **Is there a way to remove them, or are they insignificant?**

Oracle site has a 'Java SE Runtime Environment 8u221' but I get no hits anywhere searching for 'Java SE Runtime Environment 8u222'.

**What else can I try?**

=====================
**[original post]**
None of the 'similar questions' answered this.

ThinkorSwim (TOS) is based on java. It was working fine.
I tried upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04, but I couldn't get things to work the same so I reinstalled 16.04.

Then TOS started giving me java errors. I don't know what version of java I was using before, it was just working.

1. One happens Every(!) Time I open it. I can click 'continue' and the
   program seems to work ok, but it's annoying and it simply shouldn't
   happen.

[image: open error]
 2. Another happens whenever I create a watchlist and when I save a
    grid. Again, 'continue' works but it's not right.

[image]

I don't understand the second one, but the first one seems to reflect a java version number (1.8.0_u222) so I'm **focusing on version**.

As part of trying to fix this, I've reinstalled java with the following command:

> sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre

TOS support told me that "the only version of java that works with TOS is 1.8.0.60".

I found archived JRE and JDK versions [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html). Per Oracle's instructions, I "installed" the JRE simply by extracting their tarball into a directory /usr/java. I couldn't find comment on where to extract the JDK files, but I put them in the same directory. **Is that wrong?**

Another source said to add paths to /etc/profile.

Here are the end of /etc/profile and the output of update-alternatives and java -version.  But **I'm still getting the java error** above referencing 1.8.0_222. **What do you think is happening, and what can I do?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are manually installing a specific version of Java, at the very least, you will need to add it to your path.  It will look something like this:

PATH=/home/user1/jre1.8.0.60/bin:$PATH
export PATH

Add those two lines to the bottom of your .bashrc file.  This is assuming you unpacked it in your home dir.